# MySQL combining two tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to combine two tables as in my example?

**table one:**

```
bibid -- fieldid -- fied_data 
400 ----- 10 ------- 107
400 ------ 5 -------- 1950
400 ------ 3 -------- USA
405 ------ 5 -------- 1997
405 ----- 10 -------- 90
405 ------ 3 -------- RUSSIA
```

**table two:**

```
bibid -------- name
400 --- Postman Always Rings Twice
405 --- Postman is a very good person
```

That result would be:

```
bibid --------- name --------------------------length ----------year ---------- country 
400 -- Postman Always Rings Twice --------------107------------1950 ------------USA
405 -- Postman is a very good person -----------90-------------1997 ------------RUSSIA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using joins to fetch the data.

```
SELECT one.bibid, 
  two.name, 
  one_10.fied_data as length,
  one_5.fied_data as year,
  one_3.fied_data as country  
from table_two two
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_one one
ON one.bibid = two.bibid
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_one one_3
ON one.bibid = one_3.bibid
AND one_3.fieldid = 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_one one_5
ON one.bibid = one_5.bibid
AND one_5.fieldid = 5
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_one one_10
ON one.bibid = one_10.bibid
AND one_10.fieldid = 10
```

But it would be better to normalize your data...

BTW: Did you mean field_data instead of fied_data?

Comment: it works, but repeats every bibid three times. Group by helped. THANKS ALOT!

Comment: Offcourse. Then do two LOJ one instead of one LOJ two -editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following query:

```
select o.bibid, t.name name, 
(case when o.fieldid = 10 then o.fied_data end) length, 
(case when o.fieldid = 5 then o.fied_data end) year,  
(case when o.fieldid = 3 then o.fied_data end)  countrty 
from table_one o, table_two t 
where o.bibid = t.bibid
group by o.bibidid, t.name
```

Comment: thanks, but it returns only one meaning of: length, year, country

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at group_cancat, my mysql syntax is too rusty to provide you a proper example.  Been stuck in T-SQL land for too long.  here's some pseudo:

1. Sub query `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fied_data) FROM T1 GROUP BY bibid`
2. Outer Query `SELECT [Whatever] FROM T2 JOIN T1 ON ...`

Basically you are group concatenating the *fied_data*, then querying that result set and joining on the bibid.